# $\left|m^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}\right|=1$ and A001110

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The pairs of squares and triangular numbers differing by $1$ are so far: $(0,1)$, $(3,4)$, $(9,10)$, $(15,16)$, $(120,121)$, $(528,529)$.  Do you think  there are more terms than are found in [A001110](https://oeis.org/A001110)?  If so, could there be a reason for this?

Comment: A001110 has the numbers that are both square and triangular (difference $0$). This is completely different.

Comment: Any fool can see that 1 is not equal to 0.  The question is about the frequency of terms and the reason (if any) why one sequence has more than the other.

Comment: When you say "so far", do you mean that you have found, or that are known by humanity?

Comment: Yes,these are the ones I found in a few minutes with a humble calculator.  What the the rest of humanity knows OEIS does NOT

Comment: The editor of OEIS found it for me http://oeis.org/A182334 and differing by 1 is denser than differing by 0.  Reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with an existing solutuion $(m,n)$:
$$\left|m^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}\right|=1 \tag{1}$$
Then
$$\left|(m+1)^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}-(2m+1)\right|=1$$
$$\left|(m+2)^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}-(2m+1)-(2m+3)\right|=1$$
$$\left|(m+3)^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}-(2m+1)-(2m+3)-(2m+5)\right|=1$$
$$... \text{by induction}$$
$$\left|(m+k)^2 -\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}-(2km+k^2)\right|=1$$
which is
$$\left|(m+k)^2 -(1+2+...+n+2km+k^2)\right|=1$$
but we want it to be
$$\left|(m+k)^2 -(1+2+...+n+(n+1)+...+(n+p))\right|=1 \tag{2}$$
leading to
$$2km+k^2=k(2m+k)=\frac{p(2n+p+1)}{2} \iff 2k(2m+k)=p(2n+p+1)$$
or, we could ask for
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
2m+k=p\\ 
2k=2n+p+1
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow 2k=2n+2m+k+1$$
leading to
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
k=2m+2n+1\\ 
p=4m+2n+1
\end{matrix}\right. \tag{3}$$
Jumping back to $(2)$ which is
$$\left|(m+k)^2 -\frac{(n+p)(n+p+1)}{2}\right|=1 \tag{4}$$
and using $(3)$ we have
$$\left|(3m+2n+1)^2 -\frac{(4m+3n+1)(4m+3n+2)}{2}\right|=1 \tag{5}$$
which [is easy to expand to check that it reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2n%2B3m%2B1)%5E2%20-%5Cfrac%7B(4m%2B3n%2B1)(4m%2B3n%2B2)%7D%7B2%7D) to $(1)$.

To conclude:

> The mapping/recurrence $$(m,n) \mapsto (3m+2n+1, 4m+3n+1)$$ leads to infinity of pairs satisfying $(1)$

---

Example:
$$(0,1)\mapsto (3,4)\mapsto (18,25)\mapsto (105,148)\mapsto ...$$
or, in style of the question, using $m \mapsto m^2$ and $n \mapsto \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$:
$$(0,1)\mapsto (9,10)\mapsto (324,325)\mapsto (11025,11026)\mapsto ...$$

Comment: See A182334 to see that you missed some terms.

Comment: I know I missed some terms. My point was to prove there are infinity of terms. Similarly, it can be proved that A001110 has infinity of terms. As a result both sequences (A001110 and A182334) have countable infinity "number" of terms, thus "more terms" (in terms of cardinality) doesn't make sense.

Comment: A001110 has six terms less than 10 million, while A185334 has 15. That's what I mean for denser.  I think it is fair to say that asking for  them to be equal is just one question, but asking for square minus triangular AND triangular minus square is TWO questions, with twice the possible solutions.

Comment: Well, you asked a very precise question "Do you think there are more terms than are found in A001110?". All the other details (like number of solutions up to 10 million), you are looking for, should have beed added to the question. As well as what do you mean by "denser", since there is a very precise definition for dense sets, as well as [dense natural number sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem)

Comment: I suppose I was waiting for a list of terms for each to see that there are more for A185334, then I discovered this sequence buried in OEIS.  Do remember that the word 'dense' was used waaaaaay before you math guys stole it.  Such is the torment of e-mail math.  If one were daring and reckless, one could get the computer running to ask about the difference being 2 or 3 or 4 or what not to see what  goes on for hours of excitement to see how the frequency of the terms compare for ranges under powers of 10.